# Zuul routing with same endpoint but different services

Tags: netflix-zuul

I want to have routes as shown below :

```
   zuul:
     prefix:/a
     stripPrefix:true
     routes:    
       route1:
          path:/v1
          serviceId: service1
          stripPrefix:false 

       route2:
          path:/v1
          serviceId: service2
          stripPrefix:false
```

But every time I request the endpoint v1 on service2 I get results from service1. How to set the properties such that I can have same end point on two different services?